# How can gcc -O3 option make the run so fast?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

[Question]
I run below code with O3 option. And then, I found that the perforamce of the code with O3, is nine times higher than performance of the code without O3.

Edit : 
I want to know the key of optimization technique, not reason. This is my question. I have never experienced x86 assembly. So it is too hard to understand x86 assembly code. That is the reason I posted this question. Or, could you explain the code with O3 option for me?
................................................................................

[C code]
The code just executes addition.

```
float minmax_scale(unsigned int x) {

    // x_min = 0.0, x_max = 2040.0, new_min = 0.0, new_max = 1.0
    return (x/(255.0 * OFFSET));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char ibuffer[INPUT_FEATURE];
  double H[TSIZE];

  // feature summation and scale
  for (int k = 0, i = 0; k < TSIZE; i+=OFFSET, k++) {
            H[k] = minmax_scale(
                   (unsigned int)ibuffer[i]
                   + ibuffer[i+1]
                   + ibuffer[i+2]
                   + ibuffer[i+3]
                   + ibuffer[i+4]
                   + ibuffer[i+5]
                   + ibuffer[i+6]
                   + ibuffer[i+7]
                  );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[Assembly with O3]

```
    .file   "measure_fs_simple.c"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB1:
    .text
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  minmax_scale
    .type   minmax_scale, @function
minmax_scale:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    %edi, %edi
    cvtsi2sdq   %rdi, %xmm0
    divsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   minmax_scale, .-minmax_scale
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .text
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB2:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB2:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE2:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE2:
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1084219392
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

[Assembly without O3]

```
 .file   "measure_fs_simple.c"
    .text
    .globl  minmax_scale
    .type   minmax_scale, @function
minmax_scale:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    js  .L2
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    shrq    %rdx
    andl    $1, %eax
    orq %rax, %rdx
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsi2sdq   %rdx, %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
.L3:
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   minmax_scale, .-minmax_scale
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $2096, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -2084(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -2096(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, -2072(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -2068(%rbp)
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $2, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $3, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $4, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $5, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $6, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2068(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $7, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    minmax_scale
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    -2072(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movsd   %xmm0, -2064(%rbp,%rax,8)
    addl    $8, -2068(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -2072(%rbp)
.L6:
    cmpl    $127, -2072(%rbp)
    jle .L7
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L9
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L9:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1084219392
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Because `-O3` turns on most optimization options and no `-O` option at all does pretty much none. It's like asking why your car goes faster in drive than it does in park.

Comment: Think of optimization for code similar to compression algorithms for files and images. They are pretty similar with discernible differences i.e. the optimizer will trash any repetitive or seemingly useless code.

Comment: So you mean optimizer just discarded unnecessary code. That is only reason why O3 code is much faster than original, right? Is there any technique?

Comment: The optimizer is doing more than dead code removal. I pasted your updated code [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/RtaGHY). The code using -O0 is 125 lines of assembly, the -O3 code is 461 lines. That is a dramatic transformation. There isn't one single technique that is being used.

Comment: If you want to learn about compiler optimizations you might [start on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). This is a very large and complex subject with ongoing research.

Comment: @Medicineman25 that's incorrect. The compiler may do loop unrolling or inlining to make it faster. Repetitive code isn't necessarily bad

Comment: @phuclv yes perhaps the word 'repetitive' is inappropriate in this context.

Answer (score 6):

You code has no observable [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) so the optimizer is simply discarding most of your code.

Using `-O3` turns your main function into:

```
main:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This shows that micro-benchmarking code can be difficult to do correctly.

Edit:

As pointed out in a comment below, the posted code doesn't initialize `ibuffer[INPUT_FEATURE]`. Reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior which makes the whole program malformed. This is a real problem and the code isn't required to produce reasonable results. Thanks @chqrlie

Comment: Furthermore, the code has undefined behavior because `ibuffer[INPUT_FEATURE]` is uninitialized, so the compiler could generate just about anything it pleases, including faster or slower code.

Comment: @chqrlie I didn't look that closely at first. You are correct, of course.

Comment: yes. Unless the OP omitted code in his post, the `ibuffer` array is uninitialized, so reading it to perform these computations is meaningless and even has undefined behavior. The computation itself would have implementation defined behavior depending on whether `char` is signed or unsigned... The compiler is shrewd enough to generate no code, but would be well advised to output some warning messages for the unsuspecting programmer.

Comment: @정기빈 Not exactly, optimizing compilers often remove [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code). The code you posted has no observable effects, the results of the computation aren't printed or passed to another function. The [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) allows the compiler to transform your code into `return 0;`

Comment: but as I mentioned as follow, the result is the same as before. I want to know the key technique of 03 optimization in this code. This is the goal of my question.

Comment: @deepzero That might be too broad of a question. Optimizers use a large number of techniques and heuristics. Just look at the number of [options available for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code and experimented, reflecting your reply, with it as follows. result is the same as before. O3 option is better than no option.

```
#define OFFSET                  (8)
#define INPUT_FEATURE           (1024)
#define TSIZE                   (INPUT_FEATURE/OFFSET)
#include<stdio.h>

float minmax_scale(unsigned int x) {

    // x_min = 0.0, x_max = 2040.0, new_min = 0.0, new_max = 1.0
    return (x/(255.0 * OFFSET));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char ibuffer[INPUT_FEATURE];
  double H[TSIZE];

  for (int k = 0, i = 0; k < TSIZE; i+=OFFSET, k++) {
      H[k] = 0.0;
  }

  // feature summation and scale
  for (int k = 0, i = 0; k < TSIZE; i+=OFFSET, k++) {
            H[k] = minmax_scale(
                   (unsigned int)ibuffer[i]
                   + ibuffer[i+1]
                   + ibuffer[i+2]
                   + ibuffer[i+3]
                   + ibuffer[i+4]
                   + ibuffer[i+5]
                   + ibuffer[i+6]
                   + ibuffer[i+7]
                  );
  }

  for (int k = 0, i = 0; k < TSIZE; i+=OFFSET, k++) {
      printf("%lf",H[k]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**[code with O3 option]**

```
     .file   "measure_fs_simple.c"
        .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
    .LCOLDB1:
        .text
    .LHOTB1:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  minmax_scale
        .type   minmax_scale, @function
    minmax_scale:
    .LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        movl    %edi, %edi
        cvtsi2sdq   %rdi, %xmm0
        divsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
    .LFE23:
        .size   minmax_scale, .-minmax_scale
        .section    .text.unlikely
    .LCOLDE1:
        .text
    .LHOTE1:
        .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
    .LC5:
        .string "%lf"
        .section    .text.unlikely
    .LCOLDB6:
        .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .LHOTB6:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
    main:
    .LFB24:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        .cfi_offset 3, -24
        movl    $128, %ecx
        pxor    %xmm12, %xmm12
```

**[code no option]**

```
.file   "measure_fs_simple.c"
    .text
    .globl  minmax_scale
    .type   minmax_scale, @function
minmax_scale:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    js  .L2
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    shrq    %rdx
    andl    $1, %eax
    orq %rax, %rdx
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsi2sdq   %rdx, %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
.L3:
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   minmax_scale, .-minmax_scale
    .section    .rodata
.LC2:
    .string "%lf"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $2128, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -2100(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -2112(%rbp)
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, -2088(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -2084(%rbp)
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    movl    -2088(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -2064(%rbp,%rax,8)
    addl    $8, -2084(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -2088(%rbp)
.L6:
    cmpl    $127, -2088(%rbp)
    jle .L7
    movl    $0, -2080(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -2076(%rbp)
    jmp .L8
.L9:
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $2, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $3, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $4, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $5, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $6, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -2076(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $7, %eax
    cltq
    movzbl  -1040(%rbp,%rax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    minmax_scale
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    -2080(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movsd   %xmm0, -2064(%rbp,%rax,8)
    addl    $8, -2076(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -2080(%rbp)
.L8:
    cmpl    $127, -2080(%rbp)
    jle .L9
    movl    $0, -2072(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -2068(%rbp)
    jmp .L10
.L11:
    movl    -2072(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movq    -2064(%rbp,%rax,8), %rax
    movq    %rax, -2120(%rbp)
    movsd   -2120(%rbp), %xmm0
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    printf
    addl    $8, -2068(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -2072(%rbp)
.L10:
    cmpl    $127, -2072(%rbp)
    jle .L11
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rcx
    je  .L13
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L13:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1084219392
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```